# Python 3.4 error "Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing"

Tags: python-3.x

Using oauth2 to get data from Twitter, but getting the error as :

> Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Using the code below,

```
def oauth_req(url, key, secret, http_method="GET", post_body="",http_headers=None):
    consumer = oauth2.Consumer(key=API_KEY, secret=API_SECRET)
    token = oauth2.Token(key=key, secret=secret)
    client = oauth2.Client(consumer, token)
    resp, content = client.request(url, method=http_method, body=post_body, headers=http_headers)
    return content
data = oauth_req(url, TOKEN_KEY, TOKEN_SECRET)
```

Also tried utf8 encoded values for the variables that I am passing into def.

```
File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module> 
    data = oauth_req(url, TOKEN_KEY, TOKEN_SECRET) 
File "<pyshell#8>", line 6, in oauth_req
    body=post_body, headers=http_headers) 
File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2_init_.py", line 673, in request 
    req.sign_request(self.method, self.consumer, self.token) 
File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2_init_.py", line 493, in sign_request 
    self['oauth_body_hash'] = base64.b64encode(sha1(self.body).digest()) 
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback of your exception? It's not clear from your description exactly which `oauth2` call is causing the problem.

Comment: It goes as below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    data = oauth_req(url, TOKEN_KEY, TOKEN_SECRET)
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 2, in oauth_req
    consumer = oauth2.Consumer(key=API_KEY, secret=API_SECRET)
NameError: name 'oauth2' is not defined

Comment: Please edit the traceback into the question where you can format it properly. Anyway, that looks like a very different exception than what you mentioned before. `NameError: name 'oauth2' is not defined` suggests you've not imported the `oauth2` module, and has nothing to do with encodings or Unicode objects.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused. Will regenerate the output and update in the question.

Comment: Here z the Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    data = oauth_req(url, TOKEN_KEY, TOKEN_SECRET)
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 6, in oauth_req
    body=post_body, headers=http_headers)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2\__init__.py", line 673, in request
    req.sign_request(self.method, self.consumer, self.token)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\oauth2\__init__.py", line 493, in sign_request
    self['oauth_body_hash'] = base64.b64encode(sha1(self.body).digest())
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The body argument of `client.request` should be a bytestring. So first fix the default value

```
def oauth_req(url, key, secret, http_method="GET", post_body=b"", http_headers=None):
```

(That should fix the error in the example code)

And then ensure that the data that you pass into this function for the post-body is a bytestring, as its sha hash will be computed. To convert a string to bytes use `mybytestring = bytes(mystring, "utf-8")` or whatever encoding is correct to use.

Here is the [relevant line from the source](https://github.com/joestump/python-oauth2/blob/master/oauth2/__init__.py#L650):

Comment: Worked for me as well in Python 3.7 .Great work @James K

Answer (score 1):

@JamesK's answer is right. Full code is here

```
def oauth_req(url, token, secret, http_method="GET", post_body="", http_headers=None):
    consumer = oauth2.Consumer(key=CONSUMER_KEY, secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)
    token = oauth2.Token(key=token, secret=secret)
    client = oauth2.Client(consumer, token)
    resp, content = client.request( url, method=http_method, body=bytes(post_body, "utf-8"), headers=http_headers )
    return content
```