# Unicode Objects must be encoded before hashing error

Tags: python, python-3.x, encode, hmac

Questions dealing with similar issues: [SO 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585307/typeerror-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-hashing), [SO 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265439/python-3-3-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-hashing), [SO 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640868/python-3-4-error-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-before-hashing).

I've tried their answers, encoding pretty much any string to `utf-8`, but `hmac` still tells me to encode my unicoe chars. The biggest problem is that I can't even identify the offending variable; print outputs tell me they're either `strings` or `bytes`; in the case of the former I attach `.encode()`, but that hasn't helped.

I'm trying to query the GDAX API and am also [using the code as given on their API page](https://docs.gdax.com/?python#generating-an-api-key). Being written for Python2.7, I figured there might be issues with encoding and all, but this is just not making sense to me.

My code:

```
class CoinbaseExchangeAuth(AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, api_key, secret_key, passphrase):
        self.api_key = api_key.encode()
        self.secret_key = secret_key.encode()
        self.passphrase = passphrase.encode()

    def __call__(self, request):
        timestamp = str(time.time())
        message = timestamp + request.method + request.path_url + (request.body or '')
        hmac_key = base64.b64decode(self.secret_key)
    #print(hmac_key, type(hmac_key))
    #print(message, type(message))
    signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, message, hashlib.sha256)

    signature_b64 = signature.digest().encode('base64').rstrip('\n')


    request.headers.update({
        'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature_b64,
        'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
        'CB-ACCESS-KEY': self.api_key,
        'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': self.passphrase,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
    return request
```

The error:

```
File "F:\git\knowhere\Private\bitex-crawler\gdax_client\gdaxex\api.py", line 47, in __call__
signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, message, hashlib.sha256)
File "C:\Users\nls\Anaconda3\lib\hmac.py", line 144, in new
return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)
File "C:\Users\nls\Anaconda3\lib\hmac.py", line 84, in __init__
self.update(msg)
File "C:\Users\nls\Anaconda3\lib\hmac.py", line 93, in update
self.inner.update(msg)
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

When I type check the objects I feed to my `hmac.new()` call, it tells me I have a `str` object and a `bytes` object.

```
print(type(hmac_key)) # <bytes>
print(type(message))  # <str>
```

Naturally, I thought I need to encode that sucker too:

```
signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, message.encode(), hashlib.sha256)
```

which resulted in an error on this line:

```
signature_b64 = signature.digest().encode('base64').rstrip('\n')
```

namely:

```
File "F:/git/knowhere/Private/bitex-crawler/gdax_client/client.py",
[..]
File "F:\git\knowhere\Private\bitex-crawler\gdax_client\gdaxex\api.py", line 123, in _query
r = api_query(url, json=req, auth=auth)
File "C:\Users\nls\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 67, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\nls\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 53, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\nls\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 454, in request
prep = self.prepare_request(req)
File "C:\Users\nls\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 388, in prepare_request
hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
File "C:\Users\nls\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 297, in prepare
self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
File "C:\Users\nls\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 490, in prepare_auth
r = auth(self)
File "F:\git\knowhere\Private\bitex-crawler\gdax_client\gdaxex\api.py", line 49, in __call__
signature_b64 = signature.digest().encode('base64').rstrip('\n')
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

..So I can't have unencoded unicode objects, but I cant have bytes later on either? How on earth do I fix this? Appreciating any help on this, because I'm profoundly confused.

Comment: Looks like you are using python-2-only libraries with python 3. If there's no python 3 version, you have to port the third party code yourself (or switch to python 2.7) This guide should explain why you get these errors and how they can be solved. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#text-versus-binary-data

Comment: Cheers, man! I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

["Parameter msg can be of any type supported by hashlib."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib).

["Note: Feeding string objects into  is not supported, as hashes work on bytes, not on characters."](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib).

Thus, your message must be of type `bytes`. Use `.encode()` on the message wich will give you the bytes object.

Note: This is only necessary for python 3!

To encode the digest to base64 use the [base64 library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html).

```
import base64
signature_b64 = base64.b64encode(signature.digest())
```

Comment: all good! I was code-blind, encoding with `base64` works fine now. I've been writing 6 of these conversions in the past two days, sometimes it's all a bit of an import blur.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.9, I was getting the same error,

> self._inner.update(msg) TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded
> before hashing

The following worked for me,

```py
signature = hmac.new(key.encode('utf-8'), msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256)
auth_token = str(signature.hexdigest())
```